# Where can I find monthly/weekly historical data for gold and silver

Tags: data, commodities

Preferably in monthly or weekly denomination, for at least 20 years.  Preferably in Excel format, but csv, or other format is fine too.  I try to google but couldn't find anything, maybe I just wasn't doing it right.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/ You can download it as a csv file. Look for XAUUSD (Gold) & XAGUSD(Silver) under the list of instruments.